# Unable to bind intel NIC X710

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to bind this nic I40E:
Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE backplane 1581

my OS is ubuntu 18.04
kernel: 4.15.0-74-generic

I used dpdk-setup.sh to Insert VFIO module.
i also add iommu=on to grub file.

running devbind command:

sudo ./dpdk-devbind.py -b vfio-pci 02:00.1

i Got this erros:

Error: bind failed for 0000:02:00.1 - Cannot bind to driver vfio-pci

dmesg output:

[ 5091.393436] vfio-pci: probe of 0000:02:00.1 failed with error -22

Comment: are there any updates? If still face the issue I am open for live debug. The following steps is tried out on both host and guest os.

Answer (score 5):

There is no issue in binding `vfio-pci` on `Ethernet Controller X710`. I have followed the following  steps with success

- DPDK version: dpdk-20.11
- NIC: driverversion=2.1.14-k, firmware=6.01
- `modprobe vfio-pci`
- confirm via `lsmod`
- bind with `sudo ./usertools/dpdk-devbind.py -b vfio-pci [PCIe B:D:F]`

[EDIT-1] as per DPDK documentation [workaround for VT-d or iommu](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_drivers.html) is suggested.

note:

1. If VT-D is not enabled in BIOS and kernel command line (grub option), the work around is to use `echo 1 > /sys/module/vfio/parameters/enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode`, then follow the above steps.
2. if the interface is already used in Kernel - `Warning: routing table indicates that interface [PCIe B:D:F] is active. Not modifying`. Simply disable the interface with `ifconfig [interface name] down` and bind again.

Comment: we had a similar problem though we had vt-d enabled. I wasn't sure how to check IOMMU and tried enabling it which didn't work. ultimately finally we had to enable unsafe_noimmou mode which worked but what is the possible negative outcome for this unsafe IOMMU usage?